# YouTube API Throttling Number of Transfers

Tags: youtube-api

The number of submissions we process is being throttled via the YouTube API.  Is there a specific level/number of transfer that we might be going over?  Is there something we can change on our end to help this process?  Can you use multiple IP address to transfer more videos?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

There is a quota system in place for V3 of the API. It's explained here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

An upload takes about 1,600 units from your quota, so you can add them up and figure out if that's the reason for what you're noticing. You can track your quota in Google's [Cloud Console.](https://cloud.google.com/console/)